# Mathematica fails to correctly recognize Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex

I have a Hermitian matrix, but Mathematica gives 'False' when I try with HermitianMatrixQ.

```
H = {{\[Gamma]1, \[Gamma]2, 
0, \[Gamma]4}, {Conjugate[\[Gamma]2], \[Gamma]1, 
Conjugate[\[Gamma]4], 
0}, {0, \[Gamma]4, \[Gamma]1, \[Gamma]2}, {Conjugate[\[Gamma]4], 
0, Conjugate[\[Gamma]2], \[Gamma]1}};
HermitianMatrixQ[H]
(*False*)
```

I even tried explicitly defining the matrix as

```
H = {{Re[\[Gamma]1], Re[\[Gamma]2] + I*Im[\[Gamma]2], 0, 
Re[\[Gamma]4] + I*Im[\[Gamma]4]}, {Re[\[Gamma]2] - I*Im[\[Gamma]2],
Re[\[Gamma]1], Re[\[Gamma]4] - I*Im[\[Gamma]4], 0}, {0, 
Re[\[Gamma]4] + I*Im[\[Gamma]4], Re[\[Gamma]1], 
Re[\[Gamma]2] + I*Im[\[Gamma]2]}, {Re[\[Gamma]4] - I*Im[\[Gamma]4],
0, Re[\[Gamma]2] - I*Im[\[Gamma]2], Re[\[Gamma]1]}};
HermitianMatrixQ[H]
(*False*)
```

However, `ConjugateTranspose[H] == H` 
gives "True".

Is this a bug?

Comment: You missed the diagonal. It must be real.

Comment: When I retried, I explicitly made them real.

Comment: I'm seeing different behavior on version 13.3.0. (I'm using WolframCloud.com). HermitianMatrixQ returns True for the second example. 
Not sure what version you're seeing this on, but I'd guess then it was an issue that was fixed.

Comment: On your first example `HermitianMatrixQ[H, SameTest -> (ComplexExpand[#1 - #2] == 0 &)]` returns `True`. This assumes the gammas are real. If not, then the original `False` was the correct result. (Tip: It's a bit confusing to call distinct matrices by the same symbol `H`. Better to use different symbols. Then it's easier to be sure that we are all talking about the same matrix.)